# Reverse a linked list from position m to n, in-place and in one pass

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *reverseBetween(ListNode *head, int m, int n)
     {
        ListNode *pre=NULL, *cur=head, *front=NULL, *rear=NULL,*follow=head->next;
        int subLoop=n-m;
        if(m==1 && subLoop==0)
        {
            return head;
        }

        if(m==1)
        {
            rear=head;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<m-1;++i)
            {
                if(i==m-2)
                {
                    front=cur;
                }
                cur=cur->next;
            }
            rear=cur;
        }
        while(cur!=NULL&&subLoop-->=0)
        {
            follow=cur->next;
            cur->next=pre;
            pre=cur;
            cur=follow;
        }
        if(m!=1)
        {
            front->next=pre;

        }
        else if(m==1&&pre!=NULL) 
        {
            head= pre;
        }
        rear->next=cur;
        return head;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to read and follow:

```
    ListNode *pre=NULL, *cur=head, *front=NULL, *rear=NULL,*follow=head->next;
```

One variable per line:

This is really hard to read:

```
while(cur!=NULL&&subLoop-->=0)
```

Not sure what the `-->` operator does :-(

Your code could really do with a lot more white space between operators to make it readable.

To be honest I can not follow the logic of this function. Especially since I have not idea what the input parameters are supposed to represent:

```
ListNode *reverseBetween(ListNode *head, int m, int n)
```

What are `m` and `n` for?